# Flex SOAP Collection decoding

Tags: apache-flex, soap, flex4.5, decoding

Does anybody know why the Flex 4(.6) SOAP decoder adds the decoded arraycollection in the first element of the array(collection)based-property in the object?

*BarCollection* extends from *ArrayCollection*

Expected:

```
Object
    -- someProperty:BarCollection
        --[0] item:Foo 
        --[1] item:Foo
```

Got:

```
Object

-- someProperty:BarCollection
    -- [0] ArrayCollection
        --[0] item:Foo 
        --[1] item:Foo
```

The collection is registered via the 
SchemaTypeRegistry.getInstance().registerCollectionClass -method

```
SchemaTypeRegistry.getInstance().registerCollectionClass(new QName("http://www.world.com/Foo", "BarCollection"), BarCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

JoriDor,

I retraced my steps and found that a second difference between what I created and what I got from the sample cited below appears to be the true cause.

My ArrayCollection instance variable was created by getter/setter functions.  When I changed it to a public variable, like the sample code, it worked!  This is very disappointing as I must now consider altering my VO classes.

Not to give up too easily, I imagine that the mx.rpc.xml classes are using reflection ([describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29)), so maybe I can see what can be done about changing the handling of <accessor> versus <variable> tags.

...30 minutes later, and thanking Adobe for open-sourcing Flex...  I found XMLDecoder.getExistingValue() uses describeType and does account for getter/setter (aka "accessor").  My constructor created an empty ArrayCollection.  Well, XMLDecoder.setValue does not know whether to replace this AC or to add items to it.  It does the latter.  Moved the AC instantiation until the first call to the getter (checking for null of course), and now it works!

I hope that fixes it for you.  Key parts of XML Decoder to visit if you're inclined: setValue(), getExistingValue(), and then the problem issue performed by promoteValueToArray().

---

*Retracted portion starts...*

I too am finding this same behavior.  I don't know if this would count as an answer, but I have code that does work, taken from [this site](http://blog.misprintt.net/?p=192).  The key difference that I can discern between my code/data and what is posted at that site is the manner in which I declare my collection/array in the schema.

In my schema, I had declared a collection in this way:

```
<complexType name="Things">
    <sequence>
        <element name="thing" type="ids:Thing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="ParentThing">
    <complexContent>
        <sequence>
            <element name="things" type="Things"/>
        </sequence>
    <complexContent>
</complexType>
```

In the code from the site linked above, the collection is declared more directly:

```
<xs:complexType name="example">
    <xs:sequence>
        ...
        <xs:element name="items">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="item" type="item" maxOccurs="5"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

(In case you're thrown off, "example" is a type *and* an element in the sample code.  This threw me off while investigating how the sample code worked.  (I prefer the convention of capitalizing types/classes only.))

Anyhow, the sample code works, and the schema difference seemed to be the only difference that mattered.  Looking at the XML instances (his and mine), there wasn't a difference to see.  Each collection is parented by an element with a pluralized name.  That is <Things> has <thing> instances, while <items> has <item> instances.

I'd be interested to know what your schema and/or XML instance looks like and whether changing it to match the example above (if schema changes are possible in your case) fixes the issue.

Comment: JoriDor, I'm sorry.  My implementation of exactly what you have above (demand-initiated instantiation) does NOT work, even with ArrayCollection.  I have not found a way to make it work.  Very sorry.

Comment: Good grief... comment timed out.  Here is the balance: public getter/setter does work, though.  Line 2213 of XMLDecoder (within setValue) pushes the value onto the existing "iterable" (that is, TypeIterator.isIterable(existingValue) evals to true).  This is the "offender."  I think the logic should concat the values rather than push them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!

Making the property a public variable of type ArrayCollection seems to work. 
I did not managed to make it work with instantiating the field in the getter.

You did mean something like this?

```
    private var _collection:CustomCollection;

    public function get collection():CustomCollection {
        if(!_collection) 
                 _collection = new CustomCollection()

        return _collection;
    }

    public function set collection(value:CustomCollection):void {
            _collection = value;
    }
```

But it seems that this only works on pure ArrayCollections.
My CustomCollection extends CollectionBase, which extends ArrayCollection.
If I switch to the custom collection, instead of the ArrayCollection, the tricks listed above doesn't seem to work.

If I have some time, I'll run trough the XML decoder again.